# xgboost: which parameters are used in the linear booster gblinear?

Tags: r, boost, classification, xgboost

Looking on the web I am still a confused about what the linear booster `gblinear` precisely is and I am not [alone](https://www.kaggle.com/general/19048).

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md) it only has 3 parameters `lambda`,lambda_`bias` and `alpha` - maybe it should say "additional parameters".

If I understand this correctly then the linear booster does (rather standard) linear boosting (with regularization). 
In this context I can only make sense of the 3 parameters above and `eta` (the boosting rate).
That's also how it is described on [github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/demo/generalized_linear_model.R).

Nevertheless I see that tree parameters `gamma`,`max_depth` and `min_child_weight` also have an impact on the algorithm.

How can this be? Is there a totally clear description of the linear booster anywhere on the web?

See my examples:

```
library(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
train <- agaricus.train
test <- agaricus.test
```

Then the setup

```
set.seed(100)
model <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, nrounds = 5, 
                 objective = "binary:logistic", 
                 params = list(booster = "gblinear", eta = 0.5, lambda = 1, lambda_bias = 1,gamma = 2,
                               early_stopping_rounds = 3))
```

gives

```
> [1]   train-error:0.018271  [2]   train-error:0.003071 
> [3]   train-error:0.001075  [4]   train-error:0.001075 
> [5]   train-error:0.000614
```

while `gamma=1`

```
set.seed(100)
model <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, nrounds = 5, 
                 objective = "binary:logistic", 
                 params = list(booster = "gblinear", eta = 0.5, lambda = 1, lambda_bias = 1,gamma = 1,
                               early_stopping_rounds = 3))
```

leads to

```
> [1]   train-error:0.013051  [2]   train-error:0.001842 
> [3]   train-error:0.001075  [4]   train-error:0.001075 
> [5]   train-error:0.001075
```

which is another "path".

Similar for `max_depth`:

```
set.seed(100)
model <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, nrounds = 5, 
                 objective = "binary:logistic", 
                 params = list(booster = "gblinear", eta = 0.5, lambda = 1, lambda_bias = 1, max_depth = 3,
                               early_stopping_rounds = 3))

> [1]   train-error:0.016122  [2]   train-error:0.002764 
> [3]   train-error:0.001075  [4]   train-error:0.001075 
> [5]   train-error:0.000768
```

and

```
set.seed(100)
model <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, nrounds = 10, 
                 objective = "binary:logistic", 
                 params = list(booster = "gblinear", eta = 0.5, lambda = 1, lambda_bias = 1, max_depth = 4,
                               early_stopping_rounds = 3))

> [1]   train-error:0.014740  [2]   train-error:0.004453 
> [3]   train-error:0.001228  [4]   train-error:0.000921 
> [5]   train-error:0.000614
```

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation of the xgboost R package is not reliable in that respect. While the python documentation lists lambda and alpha as parameters of both the linear and the tree boosters, the R package lists them only for the linear booster. I think it's reasonable to go with the python documentation in this case.

Comment: @user3283722 this was an old question. My current understanding is that lambda and alpha only make sense for the linear booster ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may as well do some squats between running the gblinear, observe the results change almost every time, and claim that doing squats has an impact on the algorithm :)

In all seriousness, the algorithm that gblinear currently uses is not your "rather standard linear boosting". The thing responsible for the stochasticity is the use of lock-free parallelization ('hogwild') while updating the gradients during each iteration. Setting the seed doesn't affect anything; and you would only get consistently reproducible results when running single-threaded (`nthread=1`). I would also advise against running it with the default nthread setting which uses maximum possible number of OpenMP threads, as on many systems it would result in much slower speed due to thread congestion. The `nthread` needs to be not higher than the number of physical cores.

This free stochasticity might improve predictive performance in some situations. However, the pros frequently don't outweigh cons. At some point, I will submit a pull request with an option for deterministic parallelization and an option for some additional control over feature selection at each boosting round.

For ground truth on all the available parameters that are specific to booster training, refer to the source of [`struct GBLinearTrainParam`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/gbm/gblinear.cc) for gblinear and to the source of [`struct TrainParam`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/tree/param.h) for gbtree.