# Python's XGBRegressor vs R's XGBoost

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm using python's XGBRegressor and R's xgb.train with the same parameters on the same dataset and I'm getting different predictions.

I know that XGBRegressor uses 'gbtree' and I've made the appropriate comparison in R, however, I'm still getting different results.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction on how to differentiate the 2 and/or find R's equivalence to python's XGBRegressor?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, thank you.

Comment: How different are your predictions? It's not a deterministic algorithm. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42815075/903061) says that there is stochasticity within each thread, meaning you can set the same seed and run the same code on the same platform and *still* get slightly different results.

Comment: @Gregor My linked answer applies only to gblinear. The gbtree booster, to the best of my knowledge, does not have any lock-free parallelization.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Vadim!

Comment: Thank you for the response! Setting `nthread = 1` seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XGBoost uses decision trees under the hood it can give you slightly different results between fits if you do not fix random seed so the fitting procedure becomes deterministic.

You can do this via `set.seed` in R and `numpy.random.seed` in Python.

Noting Gregor's comment you might want to set `nthread` parameter to 1 to achieve full determinism.

Comment: While this can resolve this particular issue, setting the global seed with `numpy.random.seed` can cause unexpected issues with other processes that use this e.g. generation of train/test indices in cross validation.