# Why does XGBoost respond to parameters for the linear booster when I'm telling it to only use the tree booster?

Tags: r, xgboost

Run the following modification to the example code from `?xgb.train`:

```
library(xgboost)
data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.train$data, label = agaricus.train$label)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(agaricus.test$data, label = agaricus.test$label)
watchlist <- list(train = dtrain, eval = dtest)
param <- list(eta = 0.1, objective = "reg:squarederror", eval_metric = "rmse",booster="gbtree")
bst <- xgb.train(param, dtrain, nrounds = 200, watchlist)
```

and pay attention to the outputs. Now run the same code, but replace `param` with `param <- list(eta = 0.1, objective = "reg:squarederror", eval_metric = "rmse",booster="gbtree",lambda=5000)`. After doing this you will get wildly different results.

Why is this? As far as I can tell from `?xgb.train`, `lambda` is a parameter that is only for the linear booster (`gblinear`) and `booster="gbtree"` is telling `xgb.train` to use only the tree booster (`gbtree`). In other words, it appears that `xgb.train` is responding to the `lambda` parameter despite being explicitly told to only use a model that doesn't use `lambda`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815075/10319707) appears to blame randomness, but the results in the `lambda=5000` case are **very** consistent, suggesting otherwise.

Comment: There is an issue raised [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/466)